# Passing of values of selected radio buttons which are added dynamically by a servlet to a jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I have added dynamically some radio buttons to a jsp page.
Now i need to use the unique id of the selected radio button,pass it to some other servlet to process it?
How can it be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place all of your radio buttons within a form that submits to your servlet.  Make sure that each of your radio buttons name attributes is set to the same value.  Also set the value attribute of each radio button to its respective id.  When your form submits, it will pass the value of the selected radio button to the servlet.  You can then retrieve the value using `request.getParameter()`.

For more information review this tutorial. http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/radio-button-jsp.shtml

Comment: roseindia.net is world's worst tutorial site when it comes to "best practices" shown in the code examples. Practically all of their examples expose very poor practices, which may be misleading/confusing for starters.